# Sorting by order + one condition in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting

Is there some way in pandas to achieve this type of sorting?

this is a sample of what I would get with
`df = df.sort_values(['Name'])`

```
 Name                           ID
|Retailer|Lidl                  282
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland         256
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland|Hamburg 268
|Retailer|Lidl|Hamburg          287
```

when the needed result should be

```
 Name                           ID
|Retailer|Lidl                  282
|Retailer|Lidl|Hamburg          287
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland         256
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland|Hamburg 268
```

As you can see not even adding ID to sort_values would help, as values are ascending only after the first sorting.

This is some sort of hierarchy, where parent is on top, then child bottom.

```
|Retailer|Lidl = parent 
|Retailer|Lidl|Hamburg = child
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland = parent
|Retailer|Lidl Kaufland|Hamburg = child
```

Comment: why `|` between names

Comment: Explain the order logic you need

Comment: because this is the format of the given Name. some sort of hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could use a tuple to sort, for example as mentioned by @jezrael:

```
result = df.iloc[df.Name.str.split('|').map(tuple).argsort()]
```

As an alternative:

```
df['order'] = df.Name.str.split('|').map(tuple)

result = df.sort_values('order').drop('order', axis=1)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
                             Name   ID
0                   |Retailer|Lidl  282
3           |Retailer|Lidl|Hamburg  287
1          |Retailer|Lidl Kaufland  256
2  |Retailer|Lidl Kaufland|Hamburg  268
```

This guarantees that the parents will always come first that the children.